# How set Custom Input State Structure when User Inputs Something React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux

I am new to React js.I want to do like this when user enters a word and presses space bar it will saves as new word in an array and value in the input box will be cleared .. Right 
[image]

Code

```
  state = {

        showThisValue:"", 
        storeValue:[] // ["Walk","on","th"]

    };


  handleInput = e => {

        /* Store the value I have no Idea how to do this */

        if(e.target.value === " "){




        }else {

                      let updatedValue = this.state.storeValue.length === 0 ? this.state.storeValue.concat(e.target.value) : this.state.storeValue.slice(this.state.storeValue.length - 1).concat(this.state.storeValue[this.state.storeValue.length - 1].concat(e.target.value))

  this.setState({
          storeValue:updatedValue
   })


        }



    };
```

Logic

```
   let updatedValue = this.state.storeValue.length === 0 ? this.state.storeValue.concat(e.target.value) : this.state.storeValue.slice(this.state.storeValue.length - 1).concat(this.state.storeValue[this.state.storeValue.length - 1].concat(e.target.value))
```

But Above Code will Return Something Like this Like individual Letter

```
["w","a","l","k"]
```

Comment: Do you want someone to write the whole codes for you?

Comment: Just wait ill Update My Code

Comment: Please leave a comment when you're done updating, so I can get the notice

Comment: Not Much Logic that is One Line Code  Updated Check That @moon I am noob and I've tried and failed many times

Comment: I'm also kind of new to React, but, I guess you want to get 'walk' as the result, not 'w' 'a' 'l' 'k' . Am I right?

Comment: No it is Just a Example @moon Related to Gif Example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160328/discussion-between-nane-and-moon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you've wanted!

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var content = p.innerText.split(' ');
var editIndex = 0;
var text = '';

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 8){ // Backspace
        text = text.slice(0, text.length - 1); // delete 1 character.
    }else if(e.which === 32){ // Spacebar
        changeText();
    }else{
        text += e.key;
    }
    console.log(text); console.log(e.which);
});

function changeText(){
    content[editIndex] = text;
    p.innerText = content.join(' ');
    
    editIndex++;
    text = '';
    input.value = '';
}
```

```html
<p>
  My name is Apple.
</p>
<input placeholder="type words"/>
```